# Android builds on Bamboo are hanging for 20+ minutes on lintVital task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, bamboo

For some time now, all of our Android builds (running on Bamboo) are hanging for 20+ minutes at the `lintVital` task, at which point the build is usually force stopped:

```
build   28-Jan-2019 09:25:25    > Task :app-bigscreen:lintVitalProdFiretvRelease
build   28-Jan-2019 09:26:36    Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: /appl/bamboo/gradle-home/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/552f5f21376c4f273769ade73c6fef92/android.jar with input /appl/bamboo/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-28/android.jar
error   28-Jan-2019 09:47:00    Force Stop build feature is enabled for current plan. Either Bamboo has detected the build has hung or it has been manually stopped.
```

However, this is only the case on one our two Bamboo build agents - on the other one, the same build is running without any problems, with the `lintVital` task finishing within a second. (Builds on the development machines are also running fine.) According to our Bamboo admins the setup on the two build agents is "identical" - I also made sure that the Android SDK folder are in sync and since the line before the error references some files in the Gradle cache I also deleted that folder but that didn't do any good, either.

So, I am basically looking for any hints on **what could make the lintVital task hang**?

Or, more generally: What does the `lintVital` task do and what tools or other input (besides the content of our Git repository) does it depend on?

Answer (score 0):

Lint is memory intensive. Give your build more memory.

Put this in the `<project root>/gradle.properties` file:

```
# Gradle will get 1 GB of memory to play with.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1g
```

(or add the `-Xmx` argument to a preexisting `org.gradle.jvmargs` attribute)

Increase it if it's still not enough. But don't give more than it needs, garbage collection gets slower as the available memory grows. The default value is `512m`.